# Calling Java method doesn't work after upgrading jruby 9.2.11 to 9.3.0.0

Tags: jruby

```
import "com.emeter.energyip.#{@interface}.MessageHeader" // This is my java class_name
header = MessageHeader::Factory.new_instance
element = 'create'
print "Value :: #{MessageHeader::Verb.respond_to?(element.to_s.upcase)}"
```

It is printing value as false instead of true after I upgraded from jRuby 9.2.11 to 9.3.0.0

What has changed in 9.3.0.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't provide enough details to reproduce your issue (in particular, the Java classes you're using don't seem to be publicly available, so I can't check what methods they actually have), but I have a hunch anyway.

In particular, I bet that `MessageHeader::Verb` is a Java interface, and that `CREATE` is a constant defined in that interface.  In JRuby 9.2, such Java interface constants (unintentionally) had getter methods created for them, so that you could access them as e.g. `MessageHeader::Verb.CREATE`.  However, this behavior was [deprecated in JRuby 9.2.8.0](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/pull/5731) (and you would've been warned about it if you were running your code in verbose mode, which alas few people do) and [removed in JRuby 9.3](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/pull/5732).

The intended and supported way of accessing such Java constants is the same as for Ruby class or module constants, e.g. `MessageHeader::Verb::CREATE` with `::` instead of `.`.  Also, you can check for their existence with [`const_defined?`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Module/const_defined%3F) instead of [`respond_to?`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Object/respond_to%3F).

---

Ps. You seem to be a bit late with your upgrade.  The JRuby 9.3 branch is currently being ramped down, with a planned end-of-life date at the end of 2023, i.e. just over a week from now.  While occasional security updates to JRuby 9.3 *may* still be released, you really should be moving to JRuby 9.4 by now.

Also, while it can make sense to upgrade incrementally one major version at a time (i.e. 9.2 → 9.3 → 9.4), I'd generally recommend going straight to the latest minor version in each major branch (i.e. currently [9.3.13.0](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/releases/tag/9.3.13.0) and [9.4.5.0](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/releases/tag/9.4.5.0)).  In particular, the 9.x.0.0 versions of JRuby are kind of notorious for often being released with major bugs that get fixed in subsequent versions.  IME at least it's *much* easier to fix incompatibilities in your own code if you don't have to also work around weird bugs in JRuby itself at the same time.

Comment: I was able to call it like "MessageHeader::Verb::Enum.for_string(element.to_s).to_s" and it worked. Thanks for the suggestion. I will be upgrading to 9.4.5.0.

Comment: One more suggestion needed though. I have a code snippet like "when org.w3c.dom.Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE" , but it is throwing an error now : ["undefined method `ATTRIBUTE_NODE' for Java::OrgW3cDom::Node:Module", "Did you mean?  attr_singleton_reader (NoMethodError)"]  . Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Same issue, same fix. [ATTRIBUTE_NODE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#ATTRIBUTE_NODE) is a constant (static final) field, so you need to reference it in Ruby code as `org.w3c.dom.Node::ATTRIBUTE_NODE`.